# Add site visit counter widget programmatically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

I would like to add the visit counter widget using following code

```
VISITOR No.: <?php the_widget( "ADS-WpSiteCount" ); ?>
```

But nothing is appearing,

The widget I am using is https://wordpress.org/plugins/ads-wp-site-count/

Comment: Did you try echoing it? `VISITOR No.: <?php echo the_widget( "ADS-WpSiteCount" ); ?> 
`

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: And replacing double quotes `"` with single `'` (this shouldn't effect it, but you never know)?

Comment: too vague, where are you adding the code? is the html appearing at least?

Comment: I assume we can add this code anywhere in template editor, but to answer your question I am adding this in header.php of the wordpress bootstrap template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation [the_widget() WordPress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_widget/)

The parameters as defined as

```
$widget
  (string) (Required) The widget's PHP class name (see class-wp-widget.php).
```

The PHP class name can be found inside any of the php files. In your case there is a file includes/ads_widgets.php you can find the following code

```
class adswsc_clsWidget extends WP_Widget {
...
}
```

Therefore you PHP class name is **adswsc_clsWidget**, You can use the following code.

`<?php the_widget('adswsc_clsWidget'); ?>`

Important Note: **ADS-WpSiteCount** has some parameters need to be passed, otherwise it may not display properly, therefore you need to pass the parameters as the second parameter to the **the_widget()** method

Example:

`the_widget('adswsc_clsWidget',array("text"=> "on","block"=> "p"));`

Will display text only visitor count